# C++ file output

Tags: c++, file

All,

I am not a programming idiot, but the following code produces 0 byte files. I verified the filename is correct, and the files are created. I even went so far as to make the files read, write, and execute for everyone, and specify the files be truncated and not just recreated everytime, and still 0 byte files.

```
fstream fs;
fs.clear();
fs.open(dataFileName.c_str(), fstream::out| fstream::trunc);
std::cout << dataFileName.c_str() << std::endl;

for (int idx = 0; idx < theNumberHorizontalPoints; ++idx)
{
   for (int zdx = 0; zdx < theVerticalProfilePtr->getNumberVerticalLevels(); ++zdx)
   {
      fs << theThermalArray[idx][zdx] << " ";
   }
   fs << std::endl;
   fs.flush();
}
fs.close();
```

Comment: are you sure theNumberHorizontalPoints is filled correctly? Try using a debugger.

Comment: Comment out `for` loops and try `fs << "sample text" << endl;`. See if that works and you know that the problem is with your loop counters

Comment: is your loop executed at all? could you please put `std::cout << theThermalArray[idx][zdx] << " ";` near `fs << theThermalArray[idx][zdx] << " ";`?

Comment: 3. Yes, both theNumberHorizontalPoints and theThermalArray are filled correctly. I ran this through a debugger early on, and watched it go through the iterations. I did the suggestion using std::cout early on to make sure.

Comment: However, outside the loop, I can add a statement outputting to the file. I am going to look at how the vectors are being seen by the ostream object. I may have to use iterators instead.

Comment: With or without stl iterators, the double values are not being inserted into the stream. I will keep looking, this is very weird, since std::cout outputs the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Important parts of the code are missing. What are the dimensions of your array?

The rest of the code seems to be good, so I wrote a small test application that writes numbers [1-6] to a file named *demo.txt*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream fs;
    fs.clear();
    fs.open("demo.txt", fstream::out | fstream::trunc);

    int theThermalArray[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
    int theNumberHorizontalPoints = 2;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < theNumberHorizontalPoints; ++idx)
    {
       for (int zdx = 0; zdx < 3; ++zdx)
       {
          fs << theThermalArray[idx][zdx] << " ";
       }
       fs << std::endl;
       fs.flush();
    }
    fs.close();
}
```

Comment: The last statement in a for-loop header is executed at the end of an iteration, not at the beginning. That's why it's totally irrelevant if you use `++idx` or `idx++`.

Answer (score 0):

If theNumberHorizontalPoints is zero or less you will give the result you describe.

Comment: I checked that, theNumberHorizontalPoints = 29. I used a debugger to go into the loop to see what was happening. I can push a string onto the stream, but once I push a double onto the stream, it will not take any more input.

Comment: fs << std::endl; adds at least one byte to fs depending on platform. The zero size file can only be created if writing to fs fails or theNumberHorizontalPoints is <= 0. By the way std::endl flushes the stream so fs.flush() is redundant.